# Unable to create/delete files/folders from external hdd enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, readwrite

I'm trying to write files to an external hard drive in an enclosure holding 4 drives, thru usb. It won't let me do anything with the drive, saying "permission denied", and I can't format it. I've got a feeling that this has something to to with the enclosure itself--maybe the pi doesn't support it fully or something.

[image: error]

The drive I'm trying to access is formatted with exFat (previously with FAT32, which didn't work either), and the others are all FAT32.

Any help to resolve the problem is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Can you add the output of `mount`; `ls -l /media/pi` and `sudo touch /media/pi/V4/testfile.txt` to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a solution.

1. Format the drives as NTFS. (I did this on windows, since the pi wouldn't let me)
2. Plug it back into the pi.
3. If you still can't create/delete files folders, go to the next step.
4. Install the NTFS driver with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`. If this fails, try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first, and then try `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` again.

This should resolve the problem.